# mysql join with conditions

Tags: mysql, join

I asked this once already, but had to normailze to even have a chance at figuring this out

I am stuck on a query. A supervisor(id of 7 lets say) posts a job to the jobs table. when he posts it, he sets a group level of 0-4 for that posting...all that is held in the jobs table. now i want to display those on a page

if the job relevant_group is set at 0, anyone is allowed to see it. if the job relevant_group is not set at 0, then we need to grab the viewers session employee_id and use that to see if they are in one of the groups for that supervisor

so if the employee is logged in and his id is in one of the group records for that supervisor...then i want to display that job listing. the employee could be in other groups with other supervisors, but i only want to show the job if they are in a group posted by the job_lister_id the job_lister_id in jobs table and supervisor_id in groups table would be the relevant matching fields

```
jobs table 
job_listing (text I want displayed in this field) 
job_lister_id (int same as supervisor_id in table below) 
relevant_group ( enum 0,1,2,3,4 ) 

groups table
supervisor_id  (int same as job_lister_id in table above) 
group_number (data will either be 1,2,3 or 4)
employee_id (int id number of employee)
```

so now I need to echo all the records

```
SELECT * FROM jobs
   - if relevant_group == 0, go ahead and echo that one
   - if relevant_group != 0
    - I need to see if the users session id is in a record for the supervisor for that group in groups table
    - if it is echo it, else skip it
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the future, try to post your own attempt at solving something like this in your question.  It helps us better see what you're trying to do.  Unless of course you're not sure where to start, so hopefully this will help you with that.

Your first "IF" was pretty easy: I have a WHERE to check if relevant_group is zero.  You stated that you wanted to grab the group info only if the relevant_group was not zero, so I decided a LEFT join would be more-appropriate (assuming that there is no row in the "groups" table with a group_number of zero).

Your second "IF" didn't make a whole lot of sense to me: "users session id is in a record for the supervisor for that group in groups table".  But I saw this requirement: "job_lister_id (int same as supervisor_id in table below)" and assumed that's what you wanted to check for.  A "SELECT *" with a "LEFT JOIN" in this case will bring back the g.employee_id in the result set.

```
SELECT *
FROM jobs j
LEFT JOIN groups g ON g.group_number = j.relevant_group
WHERE j.relevant_group = 0
OR (g.supervisor_id = j.job_lister_id AND g.employee_id = :employee_id)
```

Try messing around with that, and see if it helps get you started.  If you need more help, edit your post with the SQL you've tried, and the result that you're seeing.

Comment: Bryce, your SQL is missing the active users ID

Comment: Check.  I've added employee_id as a bind variable.

Comment: ahhhh ! thyank you, that is what i needed. I had to also change my relevant_groups from enum as it wouldn't work properly as that

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure what you want, but I think you are looking for a SQL?

I think it would be best to have 2 queries, 1 for logged in users and 1 for not logged in.

**Logged in:**

```
    SELECT j.*
      FROM jobs j
INNER JOIN groups g ON g.group_number = j.relevant_group
     WHERE g.employee_id = 123 #Pull this from somewhere
        OR relevant_group = 0
```

You will need to add the users id in above SQL

**Not logged in**

```
    SELECT *
      FROM jobs
     WHERE relevant_group = 0
```

Your naming of tables and columns is not too good as well.

Comment: yes, a query. not sure how to add in a check for if the group number is 0, there is no group for zero so i want that one to always be echoed